# Specify that a Class argument must implement a particular interface

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, implements

I am writing a method which is passed a `Class` as an argument, like this:

```
public void doStuff(Class<?> clazz) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

I can then call the method like this:

```
doStuff(FooBar.class);
```

**How do I enforce at the compiler level that the argument can only be a class which implements a particular interface?**

I’ve tried the following—

```
public <T extends FooInterface> void doStuff(Class<T> clazz) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

—but get a compiler error for the following statement:

```
doStuff(FooBar.class); // FooBar implements FooInterface
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, and post the exact and complete compilation error.

Comment: Show us the `FooBar` class

Comment: Got it—the code itself was OK, the compilation error was about an uncaught exception. A try/catch block around the actual method call fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code I tried was in fact correct, and the compiler error (that is, Eclipse underlining the call in red) was a result of a missing try/catch block around the call.

There are two possible ways to achieve the desired result:

```
public <T extends FooInterface> void doStuff(Class<T> clazz) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Or, less elaborate:

```
public void doStuff(Class<? extends FooInterface> clazz) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your statement but it seems to work. Please have a look at the code below. I don't know the exact class definitions, but here in this case

```
t.doStuff(Foo.class)
```

works but

```
t.doStuff(Faa.class)
```

does not

```
public class Test{
public <T extends FooInterface> void doStuff(Class<T> clazz) {
    /* do stuff */
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.doStuff(Foo.class); //This one compiles fine
    //g.doStuff(Faa.class);  <-- This line gives error
}
}

interface FooInterface{

}

class Foo implements FooInterface{

}

class Faa{

}
```

Comment: Should’ve looked at the compiler error more closely—the code was fine, the error was unrelated, See above.

Comment: Yeah agree totally :-)